# SurveyJS accessibility issues with dropdown options not being read by screen reader (NVDA)

Tags: surveyjs

When I'm testing with NVDA, the dropdown options are being read as "blank".

I've seen the same issue raised here for Angular: https://github.com/surveyjs/survey-library/issues/5724

We are using the following:

- ```
  "survey-core": "^1.9.80"
  ```
- ```
  "survey-creator": "^1.7.7"
  ```
- ```
  "survey-vue-ui": "^1.9.78"
  ```

for our VueJS frontend.

I haven't been able to find a solution for this, does anyone have any ideas on what I could do this resolve this?